Which Version of Proverbs 1:7 is more faithful to the original?
Proverbs 1:7 is presented in different phraseology across Versions, for instance:
American Standard Version:

The fear of Jehovah is the beginning of knowledge; But the foolish despise wisdom and instruction.

Aramaic Bible in Plain English:

The chief wisdom is the awe of LORD JEHOVAH, but the evil despise knowledge and instruction.

While most versions use the phrase ' fear of the Lord' a few  like ABPE stand apart by using ' awe of the Lord ' . The latter phrase appears more comprehensive in that it encompasses the miracle of God's creation and man's awe for it. 'Fear' on the other hand is a restrictive term . My question is: which of the two phrases namely, 'fear of the Lord' and 'awe of the Lord'  is more faithful to the original ?

First, the Aramaic text is a translation of the Hebrew and is known to be in many places, paraphrastic.  Thus, what we have in English is a translation of a paraphrastic translation.
In the Hebrew, the operative noun in Prov 1:7 is יִרְאָה (yirah) whose meaning can be divided into two broad categories:

fear or terror  This included places such as Isa 7:25, Eze 30:13, 1:18, Jonah 1:10, 16, Deut 2:25, Ps 55:5, etc.  This is the minority meaning.

Fear of God, meaning extreme reverence inducing piety, eg, Gen 2:11, Ex 20:20, 2 Sam 23:3, 2 Chron 19:9, Neh 5:9, 15, Job 6:14, 15:4, 22:4, 28:28, Ps 5:7, 19:9, 34:11, 90:11, 119:38, Prov 1:7, 29, 2:5, 8:13, 9:10, 10:27, 14:26, 27, 15:16, 33, 16:6, 19:23, 22:4, 23:17, Isa 11:2, 3, etc.


It is instructive that this word occurs 41 times in the OT, with 14 occurring in Proverbs.  It is also significant that the word, in Proverbs, always occurs in the phrase, "The fear of the LORD" and is the source of something important:

Prov 1:7 - The fear of the LORD is the beginning of knowledge
(in consequence to V7) Prov 1:29 - they hated knowledge and chose not to fear the LORD
Prov 2:5 - you will discern the fear of the LORD and discover the knowledge of God
Prov 8:13 - To fear the LORD is to hate evil
Prov 9:10 - The fear of the LORD is the beginning of wisdom
Prov 10:27 - The fear of the LORD prolongs life
Prov 14:26 - He who fears the LORD is secure in confidence
Prov 14:27 - The fear of the LORD is a fountain of life
Prov 15:16 - Better a little with the fear of the LORD than great treasure with turmoil.
Prov 15:33 - The fear of the LORD is the instruction of wisdom
Prov 16:6 - ... the fear of the LORD one turns aside from evil.
Prov 19:23 - The fear of the LORD leads to life
Prov 22:4 - The rewards of humility and the fear of the LORD are wealth and honor and life.
Prov 23:17 - ... always continue in the fear of the LORD

Thus, I note that in Prov 1:7, the translation, "The Fear of the Lord is the beginning of knowledge/wisdom" is more consistent with the style and remainder of the Proverbs.

The biblical use of the phrase "the fear of" (the Lord God) is far from being a restrictive term. It is only humanity's ideas about 'fear' that restrict them from understanding what the Bible means. The Bible shows that the fear of God opens the person up to knowledge and wisdom that cannot be obtained any other way.
Further, it goes so far as to show that foolish, and evil people who have no fear of God actually despise knowledge, instruction and wisdom. This instantly shows us that the Bible is not here talking about human knowledge, instruction or wisdom. The foolish and evil people it refers to might be extremely well qualified academically, but if they shun or despise the knowledge of the Lord, that verse tells them how God views them.
"The beginning of knowledge" is a key concept, just as "the beginning of the gospel" is in the New Testament. It's really important to make the correct start, to begin at the beginning, when it comes to the things of God. Those who "tremble at God's word" know to humble themselves before God when seeking his knowledge, his direction in life. Those ones don't make jokes or quips about the things of God. Nor are they in fear of man-made superstitions about God. They have already started out on the pathway of true knowledge because they reverence God in the way he requires (not in man-made ways). This requires diligent study of God's word, and sincere seekers are guided by the Holy Spirit, who reads hearts. Knowing that alone ought to be enough to induce godly fear in an individual!
For me, the answer is that as long as translations show that the biblical fear of God is bound up with his wisdom, and we grasp the biblical meaning of 'fear', we stand to be liberated into godly knowledge above and beyond all the wisdom this world can offer. Also, godly fear incorporates awe of God, but goes beyond the idea of standing there, looking on in amazement - it is seeking to approach him the way he prescribes in his word, and to live for him reverentially every day.
